# CognitiveJ in Android (Pre Android N) Devices

Tags: android, image-processing, java-8, azure-cognitive-services

Months ago, Microsoft released they cognitive image analyses for Java, called [CognitiveJ](https://github.com/CognitiveJ/cognitivej). I give some tries and found it very interesting. But it requires Java 8 and I cannot use Java 8 on Android API Level 23 and early. Is there a way to use CognitiveJ with Android?

I googled but I found almost no references about uses CognitiveJ within Android.

Edited

Hmm I missed something... Microsoft released specifics SDKs for Android:

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/SDK-Sample?api=computer%20vision

Comment: No as per the first line in doc CognitiveJ is an open-source fluent Java (8). It will support from java 8

Comment: I saw it, but there is another way?